How can we monetize heavy computation using substrate blockchain?
Suppose a reputation system is built, where bad nodes (open source docker instances running computations such as a search engine) are penalized, and good nodes are incentivized. What is the secure way to incentivize and query the docker instance? I am thinking of using an off-chain worker for HTTP requests to query the docker instance by users (in other words, user has to query the docker instance through offchain worker, not docker instance directly) and paying the docker instance with the public key registered based on the number of queries done by the off-chain worker. Number of queries with some metadata are noted down in the blockchain. Is this a good idea?
